# Unexpected results in scipy.ndimage.gaussian_laplace. Inproper 2D processing

Tags: python, image-processing, scipy

I am trying to use the gaussian_laplace filter to process images in python, but I can't figure out how to specify the kernel. Without that, I think the analysis is not working properly.

I have checked the standard documentation (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.1/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.filters.gaussian_laplace.html) but it says nothing about specifying a kernel

Consider the following 8 bit grayscale TIF image:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/IIP5n.jpg

if I were to import it into python and run the gaussian_laplace filter over it with a sigma of 4 I get the following results:

```
from PIL import Image
from scipy.ndimage import gaussian_laplace
import numpy as np

file_path='White Spot.tif'
image_array=np.array(Image.open(file_path))
transformed=gaussian_laplace(image_array,4)
im = Image.fromarray(transformed)
im.save('transformed.TIF')
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lMKqt.jpg

you will note a few things, the edge is not evenly detected in both directions. The left and right side of the circle look different from the top and bottom. This is not expected because this should be a 2 dimensional analysis. Therefore, if I transpose the image before I analyze and then back transpose to the original position it should look the same. But obviously it doesn't:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vRZSC.jpg

For a typical gaussian_laplace, I would need to specify the size of the kernel over which the analysis is convolved. However, no such value appears to be present here. Maybe if I figure out how to specify the kernel then I could figure out why the analysis is different in the different directions?

I would expect this analysis should give mostly even edge detection of the circle input. It is understandable that I would see artifacts in the top right, top left, bottom left, and bottom right parts of the circle, but not at the top and bottom of the circle as I see.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I don’t know much about ndimage, but maybe it’s trying to apply the filter using unsigned arithmetic. I would try to convert the image to a floating-point type before applying the filter.

Comment: Regarding filter size: that is dictated by the sigma and the `truncate` parameter passed on to `gaussian_filter`.